# How to properly apply styles to Child theme

Tags: css, themes, wordpress

I have a situation. My child `style.css` file contain the following line :

```
@import url("../notio-wp/style.css");
```

The [Main theme](http://goo.gl/9Xz6GM) `style.css` file, contain the following message:

```
/*
* PLEASE DO NOT EDIT THIS FILE!
* 
* This file is only in your themefolder for WordPress to recognize basic theme data like name and version
* CSS Rules in this file will not be used by the theme. 
* Instead use the app.css file that is located in your themes /assets/css/ folder to add your styles. 
* If you just want to add small css snippets you might also  want to consider to add it to the designated 
* CSS option field in your themes backend at: Appearance -> Theme Options
*/
```

I've made some modifications in `custom css` Main theme field and also in `app.css` file.

What is the best way to include into the Child theme, the new `css` styles, should I simply copy the `app.css` file into the Child theme structure, or only the `app.css` modified lines, into the Child `style.css` file, next to the `css` lines from the `custom css` Main theme field? thank you,

Comment: Please provide us some code here or jsfiddle

Comment: hello there, if this helps, I've updated the question with the site link.Is that ok? thanks

Comment: Hello, did you do the style or themes of that site?

Comment: not so sure if I understand the question, this is the theme - [notio](http://notio.fuelthemes.net/) - and I was trying to apply some custom `js`, `css`, `styles` etc, I'm not the author of the theme

Comment: Yes you understood the question I meant did you created it? (I'm really love it ) I think its amazing job, I would love to have tutorial about it.

Comment: it is a nice theme but depends :) I have to recognise that I've made a lot of modifications to look like this, actually you can see that in almost all of my questions; I'm trying to do my best, customizing it according to my taste.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/80463/discussion-between-mohammed-moustafa-and-typo-78).